# Switching Panels via Index Methods

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been trying to solve my issue for quite a while and to be honest am getting nowhere. What i would like is when the user clicks the 'top' button on my panel it automatically goes to the top( and swaps with the one there.) and when they click the bottom button it automatically goes to the bottom. I'm setting the index panel manually but of course this doesnt work because its only viable for one panel (i have ten). Greatly appreciate some help in finding a method that can send the panel to the top of the stack regardless of its position.

Here is a image (basic) to help understand

[image: basic panel]

```
        Control ctrlToMove = (Control)this.bookControls[bookName];


        int ctrlToMoveIndex = bookPanel.Controls.IndexOf(ctrlToMove);
        int ctrlToSwapIndex = ctrlToMoveIndex - 5;


        Control ctrlToSwap = bookPanel.Controls[ctrlToSwapIndex];


        this.bookPanel.Controls.SetChildIndex(ctrlToMove, ctrlToSwapIndex);
        this.bookPanel.Controls.SetChildIndex(ctrlToSwap, ctrlToMoveIndex);
```

Comment: What's with the magic number 5 in your code?

Comment: Yes Sorry, i took the advice and added a screenshot to try and help explain what i mean, deleted the previous topic

Comment: As for the 5, since there is ten panels if the middle panel is selected it will go to the top, unfortunately like i mentioned only the middle panel will do this since its 'hard coded ' other panels will throw an exception

Comment: What is the parent container?  A FlowLayoutPanel, TableLayoutPanel, etc.

Comment: Its is a FlowLayoutPanel.

Comment: @user2637869 you just want to swap their positions without no need to swap their indices in `Controls`?

Comment: What is the exception that gets thrown?

Comment: @DavidTansey looks like that there is no exception here.

Comment: Index -4 is out of range is the exception if i select say the third panel down and click the moveToTop button. Not sure what you mean king king sorry

Comment: @user2637869 do you need always one item per row? Or is it possible to have several items in one row in panel?

Comment: @user2637869 if you just want to move a control to top or bottom, you don't need to deal with your control index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your drawing, I made a UserControl with a button on it:

```
void uc_ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  UserControl1 uc = sender as UserControl1;
  if (uc != null) {
    int childIndex = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.GetChildIndex(uc);
    if (childIndex > 0) {
      UserControl1 ucTop = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls[0] as UserControl1;
      flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(uc, 0);
      flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(ucTop, childIndex);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your picture you have one control per row in panel. Thus I suggest you to use `TableLayoutPanel` instead of `FlowLayoutPanel`. Also I'd create user control for items in panel. E.g. it will have name `PriorityUserControl` and four buttons to increase, decrease, maximize, minimize it's 'priority' (I placed buttons horizontally just to save place on screen):

[image]

Next, create four events in this user control:

```
public event EventHandler PriorityMaximized;
public event EventHandler PriorityIncreased;
public event EventHandler PriorityDecreased;
public event EventHandler PriorityMinimized;
```

And rise appropriate event when button clicked:

```
private void topButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (PriorityMaximized != null)
        PriorityMaximized(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

That's it. We have user control which tells whether it want to move up or down. Now add user controls to TableLayoutPanel (either manually or dynamically) and **subscribe same event handlers of these four events to ALL user controls**. Something like:

```
// create user control and attach event handlers 
PriorityUserControl control = new PriorityUserControl();
control.PriorityMaximized += priorityUserControl_PriorityMaximized;
control.PriorityMinimized += priorityUserControl_PriorityMinimized;
control.PriorityIncreased += priorityUserControl_PriorityIncreased;
control.PriorityDecreased += priorityUserControl_PriorityDecreased;
// add another row to table
panel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
panel.RowCount = panel.RowStyles.Count;
// add control table layout panel
panel.Controls.Add(control);
panel.SetRow(control, panel.RowCount - 1);
```

Good. All you should do now is implement these event handlers. It's simple. E.g. decreasing priority (i.e. moving down):

```
private void priorityUserControl_PriorityDecreased(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // sender is a control where you clicked Down button
    Control currentControl = (Control)sender;
    // get position in panel
    var position = panel.GetPositionFromControl(currentControl);
    // just to be sure control is not one at the bottom
    if (position.Row == panel.RowCount - 1)
        return;
    // we want to switch with control beneath current        
    Control controlToSwitch = panel.GetControlFromPosition(0, position.Row + 1);
    // move both controls
    panel.SetRow(currentControl, position.Row + 1);
    panel.SetRow(controlToSwitch, position.Row);            
}
```

Now implementation of maximizing priority (i.e. moving to top):

```
private void priorityUserControl_PriorityMaximized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control currentControl = (Control)sender;
    var position = panel.GetPositionFromControl(currentControl);

    if (position.Row == 0 || panel.RowCount < 2)
        return;

    Control topControl = panel.GetControlFromPosition(0, 0);
    panel.SetRow(currentControl, 0);
    panel.SetRow(topControl, position.Row);  
}
```

I believe you will create rest two handlers by yourself.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The key of what you want is setting up a clear and extendable algorithm capable to deal with the different positions of the `Panels`. Here you have a simple code showing certain approach to this problem:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int[] panelLocations;
    Point[] pointLocations;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panelLocations = new int[5];
        pointLocations = new Point[5];
        panelLocations[1] = 1;
        panelLocations[2] = 2;
        panelLocations[3] = 3;
        pointLocations[1] = new Point(panel1.Left, panel1.Top); 
        pointLocations[2] = new Point(panel2.Left, panel2.Top);
        pointLocations[3] = new Point(panel3.Left, panel3.Top);
    }

    private void relocate(int curPanel, bool goTop)
    {
        int curLoc = panelLocations[curPanel];
        int newLoc = curLoc - 1;
        if (!goTop)
        {
            newLoc = curLoc + 1;
        }

        if (newLoc < 1) newLoc = 3;
        if (newLoc > 3) newLoc = 1;

        if (newLoc != curLoc)
        {
            int otherIndex = Array.IndexOf(panelLocations, newLoc);
            panelLocations[curPanel] = newLoc;
            relocatePanel(curPanel);

            panelLocations[otherIndex] = curLoc;
            relocatePanel(otherIndex);
        }
    }

    private void relocatePanel(int curIndex)
    {
        if (curIndex == 1)
        {
            panel1.Location = pointLocations[panelLocations[1]];
        }
        else if (curIndex == 2)
        {
            panel2.Location = pointLocations[panelLocations[2]];
        }
        else if (curIndex == 3)
        {
            panel3.Location = pointLocations[panelLocations[3]];
        }

    }

    private void buttonTop1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        relocate(1, true);
    }

    private void buttonBottom1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        relocate(1, false);
    }
}
```

Open a new project, add 3 panels (`Panel1`, `Panel2` and `Panel3`... better put different background colors) and include two buttons (`buttonUp` and `buttonDown`). This code will make the `Panel1` to go up and down (by changing its position with the other panels).

The idea is pretty simple: at the start you store the positions of all the Panels in an array. In another array, you store where each panel is located every time (1 is the original position of `Panel1`, etc.).

It is a quite simple code which you can improve and extend as much as required, but the idea is pretty reliable and you can use it in any case: a set of fixed positions through which the panels will be moving.